# Still having problems with having white parts and background not covering all the background

Tags: html, css, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Still having problems with having white parts and background not covering all the background, it's one of the most simple stuff and I can't manage to figure it out, I've been testing out different codes and videos all over the internet and can't get it to work.
The webpage is just an index with 3 buttons, maths, physics and chemistry (each web aren't done yet), 3 font awesome icons and 3 black images with 0.5 opacity all along with a background that ISN'T on the internet because I edited it out in my desk.

[image: What should look like on it's entirety]

[image: What the issue is]

The code is on the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/18f289db08.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
</html>
<meta name="author" content="Iván Camacho"/>
<meta charset="UTF-8" content="Iván Camacho"/>
<meta name="author" content="Iván Camacho"/>
<meta name="author" content="Iván Camacho"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<style>

body {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-attachment:local;
background-image: url("2022-03-08\ \(3\).png");
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="Negro3">
        <img src="Fondo_Negro - copia.jpg" width="270" height="310">
        </div> 

<div class="Negro2">
    <img src="Fondo_Negro - copia (2).jpg" width="270" height="310">
     </div>    

<div class="Negro1">
<img src="Fondo_Negro.jpg" width="270" height="310">
</div>
    
<div class="superscript">
<i class="fa fa-superscript" style="font-size:60px;color:white;"></i>
</div>

<div class="calculator">
    <i class="fa fa-calculator" style="font-size:60px;color:white;"></i>
</div>

<div class="flask">
    <i class="fa fa-flask" style="font-size:60px;color:white;"></i>
</div>  

    <div class="Sciencestudio">
    <h1> Science studio </h1>
    </div>
<p>  <a href="https://google.es"> google link </a> <img src="https://www.google.com/search?q=imagen&rlz=1C1CAFB_enES711ES711&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBudns5aT2AhVDrxoKHVc9DR8Q_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1242&bih=568&dpr=1.1#imgrc=GEeCSbujNt4WcM"/>  cuerpo </p>

<div class="Matemáticas"> <p2> <a href="file:///C:/Users/xtrem/OneDrive/Escritorio/TICO%20Web%20Iv%C3%A1n%20Camacho%20Moya/Matem%C3%A1ticas.html" style="color:aliceblue"> MATEMÁTICAS </a> </p2> </div>
<div class="FÍSICA"> <p2> <a href="file:///C:/Users/xtrem/OneDrive/Escritorio/TICO%20Web%20Iv%C3%A1n%20Camacho%20Moya/F%C3%ADsica.html" style="color:aliceblue"> FÍSICA </a> </p2> </div>
<div class="QUÍMICA"> <p2> <a href="file:///C:/Users/xtrem/OneDrive/Escritorio/TICO%20Web%20Iv%C3%A1n%20Camacho%20Moya/Qu%C3%ADmica.html" style="color:aliceblue"> QUÍMICA </a> </p2> </div>

</body>


</html>
```

And the CSS code is:

```
.Negro1{
    position:relative;
    bottom: 70px;
    left: 1550px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.Negro2{
    position:relative;
    top: 245px;
    left: 1225px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.Negro3{
    position:relative;
    top: 560px;
    left: 900px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.Sciencestudio{
    position:relative;
    left:60%;
    bottom:790px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: azure;
    font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.superscript{
    position:relative;
    left:169%;
    bottom:300px;
    scale: 3;
    color:aliceblue;
}

.calculator{
    position:relative;
    left:126.5%;
    bottom:350px;
    scale: 2.5;
}

.flask{
    position:relative;
    left:161%;
    bottom:405px;
    scale: 2.5;
}

.Matemáticas{
    position:relative;
    left:75.5%;
    bottom:630px;
    scale: 1.5;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
} 

.FÍSICA{
    position:relative;
    left:95%;
    bottom:650px;
    scale: 1.5;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.QUÍMICA{
    position:relative;
    left:112%;
    bottom:670px;
    scale: 1.5;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: I've tried with cover instead of contain but the background gets expanded and I don't want to be able to the user to move around with the arrow, I just want an static image without the possibility to move around with the bars

Comment: Can you please create a sandbox.

Comment: This doesn't look like a background problem, it certainly is a body height/width problem since the content follows the background size and not the window size

Comment: what's a sandbox??

Comment: oh and that might be the issue @savageGoat , do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: A sandbox is a platform that lets you run code, usually used to have a complete view of your code and how it reacts. It helps to undestand the code you want us to help you with. Loads of sandbox websites out there, CodeSandbox, CodePen, JSFiddle, etc. Just pick one, paste your code, and share the link

Comment: but can't you just tell me how to adjust the height and width, I will post the sandbox if needed but it's going to take me some time